# Bootstrap は導入方法による違いがあるのか知りたい

Tags: sass, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap 4 の導入方法について、下記２つの違いを知りたいです。
完全にどちらでも同じなのでしょうか？

- CDN
- ソースファイルをダウンロード

例えば、用意されたスタイルに変更を加えたい場合はこちらの導入方法でないとできない、というように「こういうことをしたいならこちらの導入方法がよい」というような差異はあるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

より正確には、 bootstrap を導入するには次の２つの方法があります。(コンパイル済み css を、ダウンロードして自前で配布するのは、 CDN からダウンロードするのとほぼ同じ効果なため、一旦無視します)

1. CDN からダウンロードして使う
2. sass ファイルをコンパイルして使う

bootstrap のフレームワーク自体は sass で記述されていて、それによって、特に利用者視点煮立った場合、単なる css では実現できない以下の効用が得られています。

- もろもろのオプションや色、幅などなどを変数化することで、利用者がそれを自ら設定してカスタマイズできるようにする

それについての説明資料は、以下になります。 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/

また、本格的にウェブサイトのデザインを行うのであれば、 css を構造化して取り扱うための何らかの機構を利用したくなるかとおもっていて、 sass は、ただその構造化機能のためだけであっても、導入する価値のある仕組みであると個人的には思っています。

なので、自分でしたら:

- 練習用であったりして、 bootstrap のデフォルトのテーマ(色使い、 width とかもろもろ)をそのまま使って問題ないぐらいサイトのデザインを行わないならば CDN を。
- 自分でテーマをカスタマイズしていくならば sass コンパイルを

するのが良いのではないか、と思います。